# A problem about normal distribution, independent random variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n $ are independent identically distributed random variables, $ a_1, ..., a_n,b_1,...,b_n $ are non-zero constants. Is it true that if $ \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\alpha_i $ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i\alpha_i$ are independent, then $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n $ are normal variables?

Comment: Can anyone explain me why was this question closed?

Comment: It wasn't even a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called the Darmois-Skitovich theorem. Of course, one needs to add the
condition that  $a_jb_j\neq 0$.

The reference is
MR0346969 Kagan, A. M.; Linnik, Yu. V.; Rao, C. R., Characterization problems in mathematical statistics. Translated from the Russian by B. Ramachandran. John Wiley & Sons, New York-London-Sydney, 1973.